# How do you setup and manage a critical section in a Windows COM Component

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, com

I have an IE Browser Helper Object.  The BHO is implemented as a COM object.  At first I thought the lifecycle of the BHO was on a per-page navigation cycle, but it appears to actually be on a per-event lifecycle.  This means that the BHO is instantiated and executed once for each event and there are many events per navigation.  I need a critical section that is called from the BHO that is separate of the lifecycle of the BHO.  Unfortunately, it appears that static variables are not retained as it appears that each event gets its own COM server.  I'm thinking that the solution is to run a separate process that fires up with IE (the BHO will check for a running instance, and if found, use it, otherwise it will spawn the process).  Then the critical section would be inside the secondary process.  Would this be the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: COM objects are reference counted. If you need your COM object to survive, increment the reference count by one.

Comment: So when IE dereferences it, then it still has a reference so it survives.  Does that mean that when IE needs another reference that the last one is still around and gets reused?

Comment: When I return 2 instead of 1 in the AddRef method, the dispatch to the event handler never happens as I am speculating that IE is expecting a value of 1 for the AddRef and any other value is seen as an error.  Of course, I have no way to prove this empirically, but anecdotally this appears to be what's happening.

Comment: You do not increment the reference count by incrementing the **return value** of `AddRef`. See [Introduction to COM and ATL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/727z646z.aspx) for a quick intro, particularly the section [Introduction to COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwa2bx93.aspx).

Comment: None of this documentation tells you HOW to tell IE to increment its reference counter to the BHO.

Comment: Because that's not IE's job. It's **your** job, since you are the implementor. You should **thoroughly** read the documentation I linked to. It doesn't appear that you have the basics straight yet. COM isn't very complicated. But there are a few ground rules you absolutely, positively must know about.

Comment: I understand that the COM Server hold the reference(s) to the COM object, and they are allocated as a caller asks for them.  The behavior I am seeing in IE is that it always creates a new COM Server for each event that the BHO is subjected to.  So, it appears the IE is ignoring the rules for COM.  I would be very happy to find out I'm wrong and there's a place where I can simply increment a counter on the event call, but I've read the documentation pretty well and feel like I understand the lifecycle, but from what I've read the container, such as IE is responsible for managing the REF count.

Comment: You still have this completely backwards. It's the COM objects that manage their reference count. It is incremented for each successful call to `AddRef`/`QueryInterface`, and decremented for each call to `Release`. When it reaches zero, the object is free to destroy itself. A client **can** decide to call `CoCreateInstance` instead of reusing an existing COM object, and that is not a violation of any rules, as long as it properly acquires and releases interface pointers as appropriate.

Comment: " A client can decide to call CoCreateInstance instead of reusing an existing COM object" And that appears to be precisely what is happening as when I manipulate the reference count IE is still spawning a new BHO for the dispatched events.  I know this is happening because the Invoke method of the COM object is being called on multiple threads simultaneously, but static values (specifically a CRITICAL_SECTION lock) is being initialized in each call, thus indicating that the static value is not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with BHO's but I can tell you what's going on from the COM point of view.

Internet Explorer (the COM client) decides when it wants to create a new COM object; You don't have any control over that. You say IE creates one object per event; I don't know but I believe you.

The problem is that you are initializing shared data (it's static, so it's shared) from the object's constructor. You can't do that. That can only possibly work if there can only be one instance of your object per process at any given time, and the rules of COM don't allow you to assume that. Even if IE were to use the same object per page navigation cycle, what would happen if your IE process had multiple pages open? The shared data needs to be initialized outside of the objects.

Have you considered a static variable initialized from a static method that does the deed?

There is also the Singleton pattern which ATL supports, but I don't recommend it. IE probably assumes that when it asks for a new object, it gets a **new** object, not a copy of the existing one. Don't play tricks behind IE's back.

The exact mechanism you should use depends on the details of what you are trying to do. What's the exact scope of the shared data? You don't provide a lot of details, but you said "Critical Section" so there is multi-threading involved and that can really tricky in a DLL.

I wonder: Are you sure you really need critical sections? The IE object model is Single-Apartment-threaded (STA) and I imagine that the BHO protocol is STA as well, in which case you don't need to worry about threads or critical sections, *unless* you are creating threads yourself.

Some clarifications about the chain of comments under the question:

Artificially increasing the return value of Release() or AddRef() is legal, but doesn't change anything. It is conventional for both methods to return a real reference count, but that's just as a courtesy for debugging purposes and you cannot rely on it. The object is only required to return a non-zero value - any non-zero value - when there is at least one outstanding reference.

Calling AddRef() on yourself only adds (significantly) to your coding burden because you need to track that extra reference and somehow get rid of it at some point. And it will have no impact whatsoever on how, or when, Internet Explorer requests a new object. It cannot have any impact, as you can infer from my previous point, because Internet Explorer doesn't know or care about how many outstanding references the object has. It only cares about how many references IE itself owns. I think you have already discovered this by yourself. IE doesn't "expect" 1 or 2 from AddRef(); it expects non-zero.